# Heroku can't find user but works in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I'm hitting a problem with my heroku deployment. Here is the log:

```
   2014-04-29T16:41:59.782999+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/lines/33/edit" for 94.174.113.168 at 2014-04-29 16:41:59 +0000
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.782933+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/lines/33/edit" for 94.174.113.168 at 2014-04-29 16:41:59 +0000
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804819+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804823+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=0):
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804826+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/_history.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_lines__history_html_erb__3033746240219592358_69949428301200'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804824+00:00 app[web.1]:   config/initializers/paper_trail.rb:4:in `user'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804854+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/_history.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_lines__history_html_erb__3033746240219592358_69949428301200'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804828+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/_history.html.erb:4:in `each'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804856+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/edit.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_lines_edit_html_erb__4129892984524241027_69949427894700'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804869+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/_history.html.erb:4:in `each'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804871+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/_history.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_lines__history_html_erb__3033746240219592358_69949428301200'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804872+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/edit.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_lines_edit_html_erb__4129892984524241027_69949427894700'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804875+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804874+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804857+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804858+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804864+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804865+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=0):
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804866+00:00 app[web.1]:   config/initializers/paper_trail.rb:4:in `user'
    2014-04-29T16:41:59.804868+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/lines/_history.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_lines__history_html_erb__3033746240219592358_69949428301200'
```

The offending initializer is as follows:

```
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    def user
      User.find self.whodunnit.to_i
    end

    def nextversion
        self.next
    end
  end
end
```

Which is getting called in the _history view with the following:

```
<%= gravatar_for version.user %><%= link_to  version.user.username, user_path(version.user) %>
```

This works fine in development and appears to work fine in production on most edit pages but on one I am encountering this error. I wanted to check the version in the console but it seems I can't access paper_trail Versions in the console at all, I can only assume this is because I don't have a Version model, only a table and a controller.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have over thirty @lines and it's only one that is throwing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting following error

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=0)`

on the following method

```
def user
  puts "Value of whodunnit is -----------> #{self.whodunnit}"
  User.find self.whodunnit.to_i
end
```

which is called in

```
<%= gravatar_for version.user %><%= link_to  version.user.username, user_path(version.user) %>
```

because `self.whodunnit.to_i` is returning `0`. That means, `whodunnit` is either `""` or `nil` or `0`. Please set the correct value of `whodunnit` attribute. Also, you can check the current value of `whodunnit` by adding a `logger` or `puts` statement in `PaperTrail::Version# user` method.

Comment: I can't set the value of whodunnit without console access. I'm afraid I don't see where a puts statement would show up if the page won't load due to the error.

Comment: Ok so the log now has `2014-04-29T17:51:16.264805+00:00 app[web.1]: Value of whodunnit is -----------> ` with nothing after it. So it's nil, right? I guess I need to change my code so it can cope with nil?

Comment: YES..Thats what you would need to do.

Comment: can I just add .try onto those calls which use user?

Comment: `try` method works only when the caller is nil. For example `version.try(:user)` if version is not nil then only user method would be invoked.

Comment: Ok I've got rid of the error now so that it displays without the username at all. I still don't know why it happened but at least it's not crashing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not ran your seed.rb file (heroku run rake db:seed) to create the user or you  just are looking for an user that is not defined anymore (like deleted for example).

When you delete a user that had id=0 the next user will have id=1.

Just for sure, o recommend that you enter on your console (heroku run console) and try to find it by yourself (Client.find(0)) or try to list all of them (Client.all) to see if the user with id=0 is defined.

Hope it helps

Comment: I've only created one user and that user created all the edits so therefore whodunnit should always be user id=1.

Comment: I can't see what is in the whodunnit column because I don't appear to be able to access Versions in the console.

Comment: If its yours, you can access... Try to list all users. The fact is that the user with id=0 do not exist. There are two ways to this happen: first, your code are doing a plus one in some variable, i don think it will happen by chance so I think you just have created another user. I insist that you need to list all your users on your console to at least see if you have just one user as you say...

Comment: User.first and User.last return the same user, #1. It must be empty. Weird.

Comment: The first user for a DB is necessarily id=0. Check if your seed.rb are createing some user first. Maybe reset your db could help you to remove the error.

Comment: I didn't seed anything. I made one user and it has the id "1". Maybe it's a postgres thing?

Comment: I higly doubt it. Anyway: are you setting the id on your controller by yourself or using something like 'current_user.id'? Are you using devise? Looking for the code seems that you are looking for an user with the 'self.whodunnit.to_i'. Please, edit your question and add the whodunnit method, could you?

Comment: and please, add your controller code too... Im thinking that the error was triggered there...

Comment: I can't easily find all of that. That's part of the paper_trail gem an is pretty well bug tested. I don't think the fault lies there. I've got the error fixed so unless it come up again I think I'll leave it here. Thank you.

Comment: So...your method is definitely passing the wrong parameter. I recommend you just for testing purpose to add a '+1'  after .to_i  just for testing. Tell me if it worked if no other error has appeared

Comment: Adding +1 associates the wrong user with the whodunnit. Whodunnit is a string of current_user.id at the time the version was made. It is working correctly and displaying the correct user except on that one record which has whodunnit as nil. I have adapted my code so that it can deal with the nil. If the problem recurs I will chase it up but I don't think the method is passing the wrong parameter.

Comment: If your method is not passingg the wrong oarameter your user id need to be necessarily 0... Theres something wrong...you need to consider that is passing 0 when it need to pass 1 correct??

Comment: Im sorry, but did you define the whodunnit method? could ou publish it here? First, even if the method is right, I dont think self is defined as an user object since you did not find any user before it.

Comment: It is not passing 0 it is passing nil. I didn't definte whodunnit. It is part of the paper_trail gem.

Comment: self is the version. By calling version.user I use the initializer to take the version.whodunnit, extract the id from that and use it to find the user. I don't see any fault there.